# How can i remove a particular javascript action?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For my site I am using the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $("#body a").filter(function() {
        return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
      }).addClass('external').attr("target", "_blank");
    });
</script>
```

But this is adding the target="_blank" even to my subdomains. How can i exclude my subdomains from getting added with the _blank?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This naive function removes all but the specified number of domains/subdomains (2, by default):

```
function removeSubdomain(hostname, keep) {
    return hostname.split(".").slice(-(keep || 2)).join(".")
}
```

Use it like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var source = removeSubdomain(location.hostname);
    $("#body a").filter(function() {
        return this.hostname && removeSubdomain(this.hostname) !== source;
    }).addClass('external').attr("target", "_blank");
});
```

Some tests:

```
removeSubdomain("meta.stackoverflow.com"); // "stackoverflow.com"
removeSubdomain("test.domain.co.uk", 3); // "domain.co.uk"
removeSubdomain("simple.com") // "simple.com"
```

To test each link against a *set* of domains, first add a simple `set` function:

```
function set() {
    var i, s = {};
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        s[arguments[i]] = true;
    return s;
}
```

And update your `filter` function with this:

```
return this.hostname && !(removeSubdomain(this.hostname) in 
    set("google.com", "stackoverflow.com", "mysite.net"))
```

Comment: What if I wants to exclude some specific external domains from that function. For example if the link is pointing to my domain/my subdomain/ google/ stackflow i dont want the target attr to be getting added. How? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
var parts = window.location.hostname.split('.');
parts.shift();

var my_domain = parts.join('.');
```

Will always give you the domain + top domain, if you only have a one level subdomain. With more subdomains you have to use shift() for each level down. Not easy to implement a more general solution, because of different numbers of dots in the top domain (co.uk etc.)

Comment: Any special reason you are overriding the already existing `join` method?

Comment: Thanks for all this. But where do i add these in my code? Can you just put the complete code, by wrapping these inside my code?

Comment: @RoToRa , something made me believe that the join() method wasn't available in all browsers... But you're completly right! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to code your domain name in there:

```
return !/(\.|^)example.com$/.test(this.hostname);
```